# Keyboard only works while pressing holding/pressing down keys

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on VM virtualbox. Yesterday, something happened while I was modifying a simple text file in my admin/regular user account. Now I can only print or perform actions involving keys if I press them down and wait for the thud sound twice. It is not so in the guest account.

Anyone have any idea as to what might be the cause of the problem? I might have unknowingly turned on something by hitting some keys?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I managed to fix it.

Some of the solutions on-line said to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install scrim-bridge-client-qt
```

I did that and didn't notice any change. I then removed Guest Additions from VirtualBox because some said that might the problem. Then I added it again.

I Rebooted after every step multiple times.

Finally I noticed that the keyboard worked if I held down any key for a long time. I went and increased the reaction time to pressing the key in the keyboard setting... and voila! It works.

Now, I don't know if this was the problem from the beginning or if it sorted out after any particular step. I'm just glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem does not happen in the guest account, and you don't know what you did, you can use the following work-around:

Create a new user (E.g. `user2`) with the same privileges as the previous one (`user` in the work-around below), by going to the dash and typing `user accounts` and clicking the sole icon left.

After you've created the user:

1. Open the file manager
2. Browse to the `/home/user` directory
3. **Copy** (don't move!) all the *files* from Downloads to `/home/user2/Downloads`
4. Check you did a good job.
5. Now delete `/home/user/Downloads`
6. Go back to step 3 and repeat for Documents, Videos, ...
7. In a terminal type the following command: `deluser user --remove-home`

## Done!

**Why?** sometimes it's just much quicker to solve a problem then to find out what the problem actually is...  *If it happens again*, do a `diff /home/user/.config/* /home/user2/.config/*` ans find out what the real problem is.